# How to fix 'react-intl-tel-input' to support Vietnamese phone number

Tags: reactjs

Vietnamese mobile carriers have rolled out new prefixes ([Reference](https://en.nhandan.org.vn/scitech/item/6614602-vietnamese-mobile-carriers-roll-out-new-prefixes.html)).

My web application uses ReactJS framework and uses [react-intl-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl-tel-input).

Currently, the library works well with the old prefix of Vietnamese phone numbers but does not work with the new prefix ones

For example, the library says this phone number 01671234567 (old prefix) is valid, but it says this phone number 0371234567 (new prefix) is invalid.

Please kindly provide me some solutions what I should do to make it support both the old and the new prefixes.

---

### Edited

**The issue is fixed.**

After I am trying to upgrade the library to the latest version (7.0.1) and remove the import of libphonenumber from my component, it works well with the Vietnamese phone numbers with new prefixes.

Comment: Since this is a library issue, I think you should open an issue on library's github page https://github.com/patw0929/react-intl-tel-input/issues

Comment: @octobus Okay. The issue is opened. Thanks.

Comment: how to support both of the vietnams phone number ? i want to to validate old and new prefix for vietnams phone number ?